# embed a YouTube video in an XPages repeat control

Tags: youtube, xpages

I'm looking to embed a YouTube video into an XPage, probably into a repeat control. I've looked around but can't find anything specific to XPages. I can create a link to open the YouTube video but that just moves them to YouTube but I don't want to leave my site.
Does someone have an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [HTML `<iframe>`, `<object>` or `<embed>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp) to insert YouTube videos into your XPage repeat control.

Example:

```xml
<xp:repeat
    id="repeat1"
    rows="30"
    var="video"
    indexVar="number">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        [   "http://www.youtube.com/embed/XMoTb1iep48",
            "http://www.youtube.com/embed/lvs3vpmEKHg",
            "http://www.youtube.com/embed/63lYaeOJZOA",
            "http://www.youtube.com/embed/6D6PzLSlEsQ"
        ]
    }]]></xp:this.value>
    <iframe
        width="400"
        height="250"
        style="margin:2em"
        src="#{video}"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
    </iframe>
    <xp:text
        rendered="#{javascript:(number + 1) % 2 == 0}">
        <br />
    </xp:text>
</xp:repeat>
```

Make sure you use `http://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUR_VIDEO_ID` as URL.

A detailed description you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en).

Comment: Are there any advantages/disadvantages of using iframe vs object vs embed?

Comment: "Best practice: IFrame embeds are the recommended method for embedding a YouTube player because the IFrame will select the appropriate player based on the client's capabilities and available YouTube file formats." That's what google says.

Comment: Thanks Knut appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to [follow instructions](http://goo.gl/MCchVU) and put a short snippet anywhere in the XPage. Something like:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" 
width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-X2zNe3YFNM"
frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

With too many rows in your repeat you can expect lots of iframe reloads on every refresh.